# How to embed itunes preview of podcast on website

Tags: embed, itunes, app-store-connect, itunes-store

So I'm using wordpress to manage a website.

I would like to have the [itunes listing](http://itunes.apple.com/au/podcast/c3-church-carlingford-audio/id498833764) displayed in the website.

I saw a site that did this here: http://gungormusic.com/#!/music/

any idea how to do this:

[image]

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems they are making it themselves, in wordpress with custom post types and meta fields... here's the iframe link on the example I gave: http://gungormusic.com/wp-content/themes/skortheme/itunes_iframe.php?s=false&collection_id=562515255

Seems to be a simple hand made solution!

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for the same thing. so far the closest i've seen is this: I'm actually looking too.

http://widgets.itunes.apple.com/builder/

It's too small of a widget for what we want to use though, but it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

The layout and UI above was designed by that website owner.  Apple doesn't provide this drop-in functionality.

Check out the iTunes Affiliate program for access to the metadata and tools for linking to iTunes content and access to album art:

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/

The Search API will get you pretty close to the metadata you need for displaying the podcast you are interested in:

http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=498833764